# RS485 half duplex communication problem with K64

Tags: microcontroller, rs485, nxp

My board has a K64 NXP controller with half duplex RS485 comm., as shown here:
[image]
It is installed on a big machine with lots of other electronics/mechanics going on. I have 2 boards on the machine. Each board is getting 24V from a different power supply and using DC/DC (on board) it transfers it to 3.3. On the input 24V I have other 'users' also.
What I am experiencing is that in one of the boards, whenever a different user (on the same 24V main power line) is turned off and on, I'm getting an endless loop of tx enable, shown here:
 [image]
[image]
This goes forever, and obviously, the connection with the K64 is dead, until I power on it. Without turning On/Off this user, there is no problem with the connection.
The green line is the tx enable. The yellow line is the Rs485 transmission (A+).
I did not see any voltage spikes on the 3.3 of the K64 nor on the 24V when the other user is turned on. I'm using a USB to RS485 dongle which is not shielded (ready made product) - so I'm guessing an outside noise is coupled on this cable. When it happens, even the slightest touch on this cable and it starts to show this tx enables, sometimes when I touch it it suddenly stops.

a. Even if it is a noise problem, how come the K64 sends endless TX enable pulses ? I would have thought just a one time scenario, not all the time.

b. Any idea how to solve it? Maybe something with the RS485 termination resistors?
Thanks.

Comment: Your K64 isn't just sending "endless TX enable pulses" - it is actually transmitting data (as evidenced by the yellow trace on your 'scope). The TX enable pulses are an expected side-effect of transmitting data. Have you analysed the data to get some idea of where in your code it could be coming from?

Comment: I'm using the simply modbus monitor software, and it shows me errors code with the correct address, meaning, my address is 0B, so I'm getting 0B 86 .... (where the 8 is the error code according to the protocol - msbit is '1' and the 6 is the function called), but I'm getting alot of  these packets, with read and write functions which the controller didn't ask for, and just touching the usb to rs485 cable can make it stop or continue sending the data. This happens only when the different user is on and using the same power supply,

Comment: Just an update..
I've tried to disable all the exception transmissions from the board (because I've seen in the data I'm getting error packets, so I've figured I will only send correct packet when asked to), and now I'm getting the correct answer - but endlessly.
I think this is a good start - but need some ideas...